# Data cannot insert to database when no more error is detect

Tags: php, javascript, sql

> **Here is my code**
>
> > ***Whether is my if-else statement got problem or insert there got any problem***

if(isset($_POST["Add"]))
    {

```
    $name = $_POST["username"];
    $pass = $_POST["password"];
    $fname = $_POST["fname"];
    $lname = $_POST["lname"];
    $hph = $_POST["home"];
    $hp = $_POST["hp"];
    $mail = $_POST["email"];
    $add = $_POST["address"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $pos = $_POST["position"];
    $dept = $_POST["dept"];
```

$result **i use it to check out my username**

```
    $result=mysql_query("select*from employee where Emp_Username='$name'");

if($name==""||$pass==""||$fname==""||$lname==""||$hph==""||$hp==""||$mail==""||$add==""||$age==""||$pos==""||$dept=="")
        {
?>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                 alert("Please fill in all the required informations.");
             </script> 
<?php        
        }
elseif(empty($errors)===true)
        {                   
                     if (!preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/i",$_POST['fname'])) 
                     {
                        $fnameErr= 'Invalid key has been input*';   
                     } 
                     if (!preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/i",$_POST['lname']) )
                     {
                        $lnameErr= 'Invalid key has been input*';           
                     }
                     if (filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) 
                     {
                        $mailErr = 'A valid email address is required*';    
                     }
                    if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,}/', $_POST['age'])) 
                     {
                        $ageErr = 'Only can be numeric*';               
                     }
                    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 _.,:\"\']+$/i", $_POST['address'])) 
                     {
                        $addErr = 'Address must be letters and numbers*';               
                     }
                     if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{2,2}[-][0-9]{7,7}$/", $_POST['home'])) 
                     {
                        $hphErr= 'Phone must comply with this mask: 04-4XX1234*';               
                     }
                    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{3,3}[-][0-9]{7,7}$/", $_POST['hp'])) 
                     {
                        $hpErr= 'Phone must comply with this mask: 014-XXX1234*';               
                     }
                    if(strlen($name)<4)
                    {
                        $nameErr = 'Your username must between 4 to 12 characters*';
                    }
                    if (strlen($pass) < 6) 
                    {
                        $passErr = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters*';              
                    }        
        }
elseif(mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
```

if $result==0 so my data will insert to the employee table, but it can't work

```
        {
                mysql_query("insert into employee(Dept_ID, Emp_Address, Emp_Age, Position, Emp_Username, Emp_Password, Emp_Fname, Emp_Lname, ContactNo_Home, ContactNo_HP, Emp_Email) 
                values('$dept','$add','$age','$pos','$name','$pass','$fname','$lname','$hph','$hp','$mail')");
        ?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                         alert('Registered successfully!');
                        </script>
        <?php
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("Username already in use!");                                                                           
                        </script>
        <?php    
        }
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me find out the problem and solve it.
Thank you!

Comment: You're assuming that all your queries work. You need to check the return value from `mysql_query` every time, and handle it appropriately. You can get some useful information from `mysql_error()`, too - the database will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: you might forgot to open connection to mysql server? [Connection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: But if you are new.. better head right to mysqli. you will love it.

Comment: `mysql_query("select*from employee where Emp_Username='$name'");` 1: modify `select*from` to `select * from` by adding some whitespace; 2:`Emp_Username='$name'` is pure suicide, see http://bobby-tables.com/ learn about prepared statements instead. And enjoy StackOverflow :)

Comment: @biziclop, I agree with your second point. But i back your first point. `select*from` is same as `select * from` .

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your exact schema, or the errors MySQL is responding with, it is hard to say exactly what the problem is here.  Debugging (breakpoints, stepping over, etc.) will help you determine if what you expect is happening is actually happening.

As JohnnyJS mentioned, it looks like you never [opened a connection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) to MySQL (although as ComFreek mentioned these mysql_* functions are deprecated).

1. It is advised that you use a DBAL or ORM to interact with your database.  There are many.  At least checkout [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).
2. Debug your code.  This can be easily done with [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/) in an editor like [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/).  It is possible you are never even executing the insert query.
3. Execute your queries outside of your application to see if they are working as expected.
4. You are vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you need to quote your user provided values.
5. If you used a framework, you wouldn't even need to interact with $_POST directly.  Check out [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) -- it is an excellent PHP framework
6. Also, I would not recommend returning script tags with alerts the way you have here. It is much better to update the form with the corresponding errors inline -- which if you used Symfony would be done for you.

Hope this helps.  Good luck!